# How can I use both monitors during RDP session?

Tags: windows-7, remote-desktop

I have dual monitors set up on my home computer (running Windows 7 Ultimate). I am trying to do RDP to my computer at work (running Windows XP Pro).

So far I have been unsuccessful in being able to utilize both monitors in the remote session.

I have checked the box to "use all my monitors for the remote session" but that doesn't work either.  I also tried 'mstsc/span' from Run and it says, Windows can't find it.

My monitors are set up side by side and they are each 1920 x 1080.

Comment: Does your computer at work have two monitors?

Comment: No. the computer at work only has 1 monitor

Comment: The number of monitors on the work PC is moot, it is running XP and does not support multiple monitor RDP. Please see my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

This only works in certain releases of Windows 7 and Server 2008 R2. I believe the Ultimate version of 7 and the Enterprise version of 7 will do this, as well as any version of Server 2008 R2. I do not think Windows XP supports this feature.

Comment: He is using Windows 7.  Windows 7 Professional also supports it.

Comment: @ramhound Unfortunately the TARGET PC has to be the one with Windows 7 Enterprise or Ultimate. No, Windows 7 pro does not support it. ONLY Ultimate and Enterprise.

Comment: Good News!  I saved an RDP shortcut on my desktop and modified the Target at the end by adding ' /span' and open RDP from that shortcut and I've got what I need now.  I'm in business.  Thanks for the comments.

Comment: This is not a true multi-monitor environment but if it works for you then that is excellent.